# How to consistently subclass an ensemble of cooperating classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

Suppose I have a set of (possibly abstract) base classes which cooperate in a certain way, and I want to subclass them in such a way that the subclasses are aware of its respective co-operating subclasses (e.g. it has the other classes as class attributes).

Literally adding attributes seems really messy for more than a handful of classes.

One way I can think of doing this is to class properties for the abstract classes which would reference a `dict`ionary class attribute (same dictionary for all classes), via mixin to avoid repeating code in the superclass module. This way, I only need to add one attribute for each subclass (and add a dictionary referencing all the classes in the module), see the code below.

Is there an established design pattern to achieve this sort of thing?

Example:

> abstract_module:

```
from abc import ABC

_module_classes_dict = {}


class _ClassesDictMixin:
    _classes_dict = dict()

    @classmethod
    @property
    def _a_class(cls):
        return cls._classes_dict['a']
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    def _b_class(cls):
        return cls._classes_dict['b']

    @classmethod
    @property
    def _c_class(cls):
        return cls._classes_dict['c']


class AbstractA(ABC):
    pass


class AbstractB(_ClassesDictMixin, ABC):
    _classes_dict = _module_classes_dict
    # # Basic solution without using the dict
    # _a_class = AbstractA


class AbstractC(_ClassesDictMixin, ABC):
    _classes_dict = _module_classes_dict
    # # Basic solution without using the dict
    # _a_class = AbstractA
    # _b_class = AbstractB


class AbstractD(_ClassesDictMixin, ABC):
    _classes_dict = _module_classes_dict
    # # Alternative solution without using the dict
    # _a_class = AbstractA
    # _b_class = AbstractB
    # _c_class = AbstractC


_module_classes_dict.update(a=AbstractA, b=AbstractB, c=AbstractC, d=AbstractD)
```

> concrete_module:

```
from abstract_module import AbstractA, AbstractB, AbstractC, AbstractD

_module_classes_dict = {}


class ConcreteA(AbstractA):
    pass


class ConcreteB(AbstractB):
    _classes_dict = _module_classes_dict
    # # Basic solution without using the dict
    # _a_class = ConcreteA


class ConcreteC(AbstractC):
    _classes_dict = _module_classes_dict
    # # Basic solution without using the dict
    # _a_class = ConcreteA
    # _b_class = ConcreteB


class ConcreteD(AbstractD):
    _classes_dict = _module_classes_dict
    # # Basic solution without using the dict
    # _a_class = ConcreteA
    # _b_class = ConcreteB
    # _c_class = ConcreteC


_module_classes_dict.update(a=ConcreteA, b=ConcreteB, c=ConcreteC, d=ConcreteD)
```

Comment: Could you explain how `ConcreteB` will use `ConcreteA`? Will it use the class as a factory (e.g. `x = ConcreteA(y, z)`)? Or use class methods (e.g. `x = ConcreteA.foo(y, z)`)? Something else?

Comment: I think this is the most obvious use case (and what I was doing in the toy project I was working on, but now I switched to simply making the other objects available via `__init__` argument), but I guess I am just mostly interested on how this sort of thing should be done in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is maybe not where you think it is.

> Literally adding attributes seems really messy for more than a handful of classes.

I would be concerned if one of my classes was dependent on "more than a handful of classes". This is the issue, in my mind, you should try to solve.

Moreover, the mixin solution has a main drawback: `ConcreteB` knows about `ConcreteC` and `ConcreteD` whereas it should only know about `ConcreteA`. The dependencies between the classes are blurred. On the contrary, hard coding the dependencies should be a cleaner solution because the relationship between classes is explicit.

Hence this seems better than the mixin:

```
class ConcreteB(AbstractB):
    _a_class = ConcreteA

class ConcreteC(AbstractC):
    _a_class = ConcreteA
    _b_class = ConcreteB
```

But sometimes hard coding the relations between `ConcreteB` and `ConcreteA` is not the best option. What if you want to use `ConcreteA2` instead of `ConcreteA`?

```
class ConcreteA(AbstractA):
    pass

class ConcreteA2(AbstractA):
    pass
```

To make the code more versatile, you can use (as you wrote in a comment) the parameters of `__init__`:

```
class ConcreteB(AbstractB):
    def __init__(self, a_class):
        self._a_class = a_class

class ConcreteC(AbstractC):
    def __init__(self, a_class, b_class):
        self._a_class = a_class
        self._b_class = b_class
```

But now, you might have an inconsistent set of classes:

```
b = ConcreteB(ConcreteA)
c = ConcreteC(ConcreteA2, ConcreteB)
```

This could happen if the codebase grows and the initialization of objects is dispatched across various modules. To avoid this situation, you may use a variant of the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
class Factory:
    def __init__(a_class, b_class, c_class, d_class):
        self._a_class = a_class
        self._b_class = b_class
        self._c_class = c_class

    def concreteA(self):
        return self._a_class()

    def concreteB(self):
        return self._b_class(self._a_class)

    def concreteC(self):
        return self._c_class(self._a_class, self._c_class)
```

Now, you are sure that `B` and `C` share the same `a_class`.

This design helps you to ensure that the dependencies are explicit and consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This makes sense. I like the idea of using the factory pattern this way.